# Unit Testing for Websites or Webforms or .Aspx page: code coverage

Tags: asp.net, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have one website which was made in Asp.Net. I want to have the code coverage for the website now.

Can anybody suggest me which are the possible ways to have the code coverage for the website? Suggestions on how to write unit test methods for Webform or .Aspx page are also welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Try following steps to enable code coverage: 
 - Open the local.testsettings which you can access from Test -> Edit
   Test Settings -> Local (local.testsettings) 
 - List item Select Data and Diagnostics from the list  
 - Select the Enabled checkbox on the Code Coverage row  
 - Double-click the Code Coverage row 
 
 - Select the assemblies you want to instrument  
 - Specify a re-signing key file if your assemblies are strong-named  
 - Click OK  
 - Click Apply  
 - Click Close 
For unit test you can have seperate class library project in the same solution where you can create unit test method. For example :

```
/// <summary>
    /// Holds test for MapRoles.
    /// </summary>
    [TestClass]
    public class MapRolesTest
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Perform test on CompareUserRoles.
        /// </summary>
        [TestMethod]
        public void CompareUserRolesTest()
        {
            //// The class which is inside actual asp.net web application.
            MapRoles objMapRoles = new MapRoles();

            //// Get role of the user1.
            string user1Role = objMapRoles.GetUserRole("Jeet");

            //// Get role of the user2.
            string user2Role = objMapRoles.GetUserRole("Vishwajeet");

            //// Assert.
            Assert.AreEqual(user1Role, user2Role);
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i am having simple asp.net website. I have not used MVC. So how can i access the controls which are on .aspx page ?

Comment: @user509685: OK. Firstly, you need add reference(.dll file) of your application in unit test project. Actually, the thing is that you don't have need to access control in unit test. You need to take business classes & its functions which are retrieving data from server. Checking whether they are retrieving data properly or not in development phase? This is the ultimate use of writing unit test. I've done changes in previous post. Hope that will be as you wanted.